# Transparent Cube With illuminating Object

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I have a cube which is set up to be glass material, and another object with Emission Node, which is glowing. Once i place the object within the cube which has the emission, it's losing it's glow strength. Is there a method to get the cube to look more lit up from the object which is already acting like a glowing source?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Emission from your "glass" is interfering, among other things. I've found one of the most practical ways to produce "glass" in eevee, is through the node setup below:

[image: GlowGlass]

Comment: This is Super! Thanks heaps for the Nodes set up, I'd never be able to figure this out without help.